# Lock or hide files/folders everywhere

Tags: windows-7

The problem with applications like Folder Lock is that they can lock/hide files/folders just in the current OS (i.e the os in which they are installed) but those files/folders are easily accessible in other OSs that boot from the same pc!!! (for example if I hide my files on Windows 7, someone can easily boot my pc with for example a live version of linux and pickup those files!!!)

Is there any application that can hide/lock files/folders in such a way that it could be opened/showed just in the current OS(and of course with valid credentials)?

Comment: Based on your description, you may want to consider [full-disk encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption). [TrueCrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt) is one of the most popular.

Comment: The first rule of security: if they have physical access to the system, there is no security. Encryption would be your only solution, such as true crypt being suggested below

Answer (score 4):

If you copy the files/folders you want to hide into a [TrueCrypt](http://truecrypt.org/) container, then they are really hidden, because they are encrypted.  No one will see them (regardless of which OS they boot) without knowing the passphrase of that container.

Comment: I'll second the use of TrueCrypt. I use it for documents that I really want to keep safe. It is also compatible with delta-backup type tools such as RSYNC and CrashPlan. I just create a container file in my Dropbox folder. Only down-side is that, on Windows, you have to be at least a local admin user to use TrueCrypt.